# find child element with same name using an XmlReader?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have the following XML file:

```
<mall_tree>
    <catalog name="SPECIALS">
        <catalog name="Popular">
            <item id="7004" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="7005" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="7002" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="635" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="210" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="531" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="216" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="214" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="590" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="595" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="466" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="175" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="564" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Packs">
            <item id="7004" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="7002" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="7001" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="7003" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="182" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="635" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Dime Store">
            <item id="688" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="207" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="378" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="488" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="215" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="217" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="461" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="206" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="190" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
    </catalog>
    <catalog name="GENERAL">
        <catalog name="Boosts">
            <item id="7002" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="210" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="192" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="635" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="688" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="531" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="530" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="488" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="201" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="197" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="378" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Teleport">
            <item id="207" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="208" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="209" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="191" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Crafting">
            <item id="548" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="549" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="550" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="552" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="553" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="554" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="556" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="557" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="558" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="165" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="166" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="167" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="168" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="169" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="170" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
    </catalog>
    <catalog name="UPGRADES">
        <catalog name="Utility">
            <item id="7005" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="215" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="213" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="216" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="214" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="217" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="218" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="219" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="220" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="221" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Projectile">
            <item id="564" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="640" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Lv1 Gems">
            <item id="451" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="454" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="379" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="382" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="385" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="388" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="391" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="406" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="394" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="409" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="397" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="412" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="400" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="415" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="403" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="418" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="421" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="442" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="427" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="445" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="430" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="448" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="436" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="439" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Lv3 Gems">
            <item id="7001" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
    </catalog>
    <catalog name="MOUNTS">
        <catalog name="Mount">
            <item id="304" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="307" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="305" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Umbrella">
            <item id="630" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
    </catalog>
    <catalog name="PETS">
        <catalog name="Talents">
            <item id="357" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="358" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="590" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="593" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="594" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="595" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Refresh">
            <item id="360" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="361" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Respec">
            <item id="363" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="364" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="365" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="366" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="367" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Energy">
            <item id="461" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
    </catalog>
    <catalog name="FASHION">
        <catalog name="Body">
            <item id="561" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="566" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="678" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="560" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="565" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="679" showmodel="true"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Head">
            <item id="563" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="568" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="676" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="562" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="567" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="677" showmodel="true"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Class">
            <item id="322" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="308" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="317" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="309" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="318" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="310" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="319" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="311" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="320" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="313" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="321" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="312" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="323" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="314" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="324" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="315" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="325" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="316" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="341" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="326" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="331" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="327" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="337" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="328" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="338" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="329" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="339" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="330" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="340" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="333" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="342" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="334" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="343" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="335" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="332" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="336" showmodel="true"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Accessory">
            <item id="622" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="621" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="624" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="623" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="544" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="541" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="486" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="303" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="299" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="301" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="302" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="352" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="490" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="489" showmodel="true"/>
            <item id="298" showmodel="true"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Utility">
            <item id="466" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="465" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="625" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="464" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="547" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
    </catalog>
    <catalog name="SOCIAL">
        <catalog name="Guild">
            <item id="175" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="176" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="177" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="179" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="178" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Marriage">
            <item id="7003" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="182" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="462" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="463" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="180" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="181" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="190" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Friends">
            <item id="193" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="194" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="195" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="196" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="528" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="529" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Chat">
            <item id="487" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="459" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="206" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Grafitti">
            <item id="202" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="203" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="204" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="205" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
        <catalog name="Tours">
            <item id="187" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="184" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="188" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="185" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="189" showmodel="false"/>
            <item id="186" showmodel="false"/>
        </catalog>
    </catalog>
</mall_tree>
```

I am trying to take the `<catalog name="SPECIALS">` node and get all of the other `<catalog>` nodes that are nested inside of it. I'm using `XMLTextReader` to read the file, is there possibly a better way? Here is the current code I'm using.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filePath);
reader.ReadToFollowing("catalog");
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", reader.GetAttribute("name"));
    }
    while (reader.ReadToFollowing("catalog"));
```

Comment: Did you really have to post _all_ that XML in order to illustrate the problem? Please remove everything not required to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the list of descendant "catalog" nodes:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("yourFile.xml");

var doc = xDoc.Descendants("catalog")
              .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "SPECIALS")
              .Select(x => x.Nodes())
              .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
              .ToList();
```

The output is 3 `XNode` instances, for Popular, Packs, and Dime Store.

To print them out to the console:

```
foreach (var d in doc.OfType<XElement>())
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", d.Attribute("name").Value);
```

Comment: You sure do like your LINQ. ;)

Comment: It definitely is.  I went through a golden hammer phase with it a while back. Then I realized how much bigger my assemblies were getting in a lot of cases.  Now I'm a little more selective.  Often, I'll write something as LINQ and, if it looks like it'd cause more allocations than a manual implementation by any appreciable degree (this tends to be LINQ's weakness), I'll refactor the method after the application is working.  But most of the time I leave the bike shed alone if it's good enough.

Comment: I do have another quick question, is there a way to use a declare a `XmlTextReader` and use it in many `voids`? `private XmlTextReader reader;` doesn't work.

Comment: It says this: `Field 'WindowsFormsApplication7.Mall_Editor.reader' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null`

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now, how would I output the XNode list?

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely what XPath is for.  And it is very efficient, and a w3c standard, to boot:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument( );
doc.Load( "TextFile1.xml" );
XmlNodeList specialCatalogs = doc.SelectNodes( "/mall_tree/catalog[@name='SPECIALS']/catalog" );
```

Comment: They both get the job done. XPath is one of those nifty tools that was purpose-built for exactly what you're trying to do, though, so it's a shoe-in here.  Added bonus: you can use xpath in almost any language out there.